# how to resolve D-Bus system message bus

Tags: login-screen, dbus

after an update i restarted my system after the restart i got stuck at the loading screen after pressing the F2 it says

```
Failed to start System Logging service.
Failed to start D-Bus system Message Bus.
Failed to start RPC Portman Service.
Failed to start User Login Management.
```

Does anyone know got to resolve this?

Using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem, but i might have a solution to you. You could boot into GRUB and select the recovery option. From there you could reinstall these drivers by using the dpkg option (you would have to enable networking first)

Comment: OK, but which command could you run to reinstall those drivers?

Comment: there should be a dpkg option, as i stated

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem on a fresh install of Ubuntu LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)!

Solved by just redoing installation!  (So suggestion: Boot from USB install media and just retry.)

The second time took much longer and definitely succeeded in downloading packages (I expanded the details are at bottom and watched it downloading them).  My guess is the first time, something happened on attempting to download packages for installation but wasn't shown to me -- perhaps some issue with wi-fi connectivity?

Anyway, hope this helps future fresh installers, GL